# combine several types of xml layouts programatically android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a requirement where there are 2 programatically generated screens and 2 xml layouts. Now i need to on the fly combine, these layouts multiple times.

For ex, i have screen 1 - programatically created, screen 2 - programatically created, screen 3- from a xml layout, screen 4 - from a xml layout

My final layout design should be a single screen with screen1, screen2, screen 3, screen 4, screen 2... with all screens sharing equal screen space based on the number of screen i input. Please let me know the approach. Some screens are having relative layout and some linear ones. So it should combine these.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to invoke `addView()` on the primary layout.  Once the primary layout is built (which holds all the other layouts), the `addView()` method will add new views to the existing primary layout.

To add the new layout, you'll need to inflate it first.

```
LinearLayout primaryLayout;

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
LinearLayout newLayout = (LinearLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_new_layout, null, false);

primaryLayout.addView(newLayout);
```

AddView also provides an index option to place the new layout at a specific point in the primary layout.

Try starting with a blank, XML layout (say called primary_layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/primaryLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, as your activity starts, set that first, then inflate and add as desired:

```
setContentView(R.layout.primary_layout);
LinearLayout primaryLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.primaryLayout);
```

Then you can add your new views to that one.  As for adding multiple times, I believe that it's done by reference, so it only sees a single view.  Try building the view in a method, and just returning the view.  Such as:

```
private View buildNewView(){

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );  
    LinearLayout newView = (LinearLayout)layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.my_new_view null, false );


    return newView ;
}
```

And call it via `primaryLayout.addView(buildNewView();`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i did as you said.

    

    RelativeLayout primaryLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
  LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
  RelativeLayout newLayout = (RelativeLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout3, null, false);
  RelativeLayout newLayout1 = (RelativeLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout4, null, false);
  primaryLayout.addView(newLayout);
  primaryLayout.addView(newLayout1);
  setContentView(primaryLayout);

But, only the last view is getting added, can you guide y is it so?

Comment: Also, i cannot add the same view multiple times, it gives an error stating the specified child already has a parent, first call removeview

Comment: @bharath Try my answer out. It uses Fragments to do what you want. You can even specify XML Files or runtime-created layouts inside the Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into Fragments. They seem to do exactly what you need. Here are the links to the [Training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) and [API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) on them.
In your xml file, you can specify 4 child layouts inside a `LinearLayout` parent, each with an attribute `android:layout_weight="1"`, so each child layout would only take up the same amount of space. If in portrait orientation, it is suggested to set `android:layout_width="match_parent` and `android:layout_height="0dp"` Now, you can label the id's of each child layout as id1, id2, id3, etc, but you can also label the two layouts you will create as something like`android:id="@+id/fragment_container_first` and `android:id="@+id/fragment_container_second`.
In the Java code, you would set the contentView as the id of the xml file (`setContentView(R.layout.myXMLLayout);`), create two instances of a Fragment by following the Training guide link I provided above, and add those views to the containers you setup earlier inside your xml files by using something like `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container_first, firstFragment).commit();` and `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container_second, secondFragment).commit();`(If you are using the support library, which is what the training guides use).
I really hope this helps you out. You can build a really flexible UI with Fragments. For instance, later on, you can replace the first two fragments with other fragments at runtime, increasing flexibility. You can even setup different UIs for different screen sizes, with a more compact view on a phone, but with much more to offer on a larger screen like a tablet.
I'd love to hear back if this helped you out!